What is the bg_startup_tracing shared preference key that always gets populated for my app on a Samsung Galaxy A13?
I work on an Android app that expects empty default shared preferences in certain contexts. On my Samsung Galaxy A13 running Android 14, that never happens. There is always a bg_startup_tracing key with value false. I programmatically remove it using PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply(), verify that the preferences are empty, relaunch the app, and it's always back. This does not happen with an emulator.
What is this key and what is setting it in my app's shared preferences?
I see a reference to it in the Chromium Android app's source. I also see that sometimes other users have it for apps they use.
Update: This happens when I run tests from Android Studio. The same thing happens when I run the same tests on a Pixel 4a.

Do you (or a library) use WebView? If yes, then this could actually come from Chromium, which powers WebView AFAIK.

The app does use a WebView. That sounds like it could be an explanation but any idea for why it doesn't happen on most devices? Is there something Samsung devices might be doing?

Interesting update! It happens on other devices I run tests on from my computer so maybe it's something Android Studio does.
